# Namespace/Group/key identification

Tags: php, laravel

When using the Laravel 4 config class, you can call `Config::set('namespace::file.key', 'new value')` and it will follow this process:

Check if there is a file called `file`.
If there is, set (in memory) The value of:

- The `key` key
- In the `file` file
- from the `namespace` namespace (which roughly translates to package)

to `new value`

If there is not,
The call gets silently translated to `Config::set('namespace::config.file.key', 'new value')` which sets (in memory) The value of:

- The `key` sub-key
- In the `file` array
- In the `config` file
- from the `namespace` namespace (which roughly translates to package)

to `new value`

Which because you are only dealing with in-memory, this works fine.

But, what if you wanted to physically save the changes you make when calling `Config::set(...`?

The issue that you run into is, how do you know if you are wanting to create a new group (aka file) called `file` if it does not exist, and then set the `key` key inside that? or if you are using the shorthand to reference the `config` group?

My thinking is that except for a couple of exceptions, always assume that the first section (exploded on .) after the namespace is the file/group, but I am wondering if it goes against anything "laravelian" or of there are any edge cases I have missed?

---

`Config::set('key', 'value')` == `Config::set('config.key', 'value')` **exception**
Sets the value of `key` to `value` in the `config` file (no namespace)

---

`Config::set('namespace::key', 'value')` == `Config::set('namespace::config.key', 'value')` **exception**
Sets the value of `key` in the `config` file of the `namespace` namespace to `value`

---

`Config::set('file.key', 'value')`
Sets the value of `key` in the `file` file to `value` (no namespace)

---

`Config::set('namespace::file.key', 'value')`
Sets the value of `key` in the `file` file of the `namespace` namespace to `value`

---

`Config::set('namespace::file.key.arrk1.arrk2', 'value')`
Sets the value of `arrk2` in the `arrk1` array of the `key` key in the `file` file of the `namespace` namespace to `value`

---

Comment: @KingCrunch, Why did you remove the laravel-4 tag? this is specific to the Laravel-4 config class?

Comment: More tags doesn't mean you get more/better answers. `laravel` and `laravel-4` are kind of duplicates, so I left the more generic one. `laravel-4` has only around 80 followers anyway.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose, I added the l4 tag as l3 and l4 are sufficiently different to warrant it in my opinion especially since l4 is a beta version so most people tend to assume the latest stable version. Would it be better to just tag laravel and make the question state l4?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm struggling to identify your actual question here.  Besides which, since Config::set() only operates in memory anyway, does it matter what 'file' the keys would match to anyway?  If you wanted to physically save config files you likely wouldn't go via the `Config` facade anyway, as you'd need to build a tool to write the files.  Or have I completely missed your point?

Comment: @PhillSparks, This question was in reference to creating a the Database Config Loader (https://bitbucket.org/hailwoodnz/database-config-loader) Which uses the same interface as the Config facade, but allows you to actually save the changes used with set as well. Hence the question, I was wondering how it would be done as just an addition to the present Config loader.

Comment: @Hailwood sorry, that wasn't clear to me from your original question.  I think the thing to look at is the behaviour of `get()` compared with `set()`.  If `get()` searches the 'config' file in the absence of of a file for the first segment then it's consistent with `set()` and if you use only the `Config::` interface then you'll never have any problems. The alternative would be a new method to create new 'files' (or groups in the database sense). Ultimately, consistency across all methods is key.  I'd be in favour of removing the shorthand though.